# Do copyright dates need to be updated?

Tags: server-side, copyright-display

Every now and then I see a web site that has an old copyright date. In my mind, I always think "Look at the sucker who forgot to update his copyright year!" Then, while I was hard-coding a copyright year into the site I'm currently designing, it suddenly struck me:

How the hell am I going to remember to update this?

My immediate reaction was just to use some server-side coding to automatically display the current year. Bam, fixed.

Later, I began to ponder to myself, if someone as big and smart as Google can [overlook this](http://goo.gl/), perhaps there's something wrong in doing it this way. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I guess what I'm really wondering is *why I feel compelled* to keep the copyright year up to date. Is there a reason, or is my chronic OCD to blame?

If there is a good reason to keep them up to date, why don't more developers use server-side code? I see these "mistakes" [all](http://www.times.com/ref/membercenter/help/copyright.html) [over](http://www.myflorida.com/myflorida/copyright.html) [the](http://www.fpsece.net/) [place](http://copyright.columbia.edu/copyright/).

Comment: but, the copyright of a webpage (when VERY old) also gives me a pretty good idea how long it's been since the page has been updated.  I tend to stay away from commerce sites that haven't been updated in 5 years :)

Comment: btw, NYTimes now has updated the year. Currently, it says 2016

Comment: I wonder if it is actually "legal" to have an updated date automatically.  ie, if you haven't actually created anything in 2016, should your copyright should still say 2015.

Comment: @ScottCarlson You could argue that changing the copyright notice changes the content ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question and not a programming question.

Comment: Treating copyright dates as the date of data update is just ignorance of the history of copyright law. Copyright dates in the US format are a claim as to the FIRST publication date for the information. THE OLDER THE BETTER. Updating a copyright year is equivalent to stating you are giving up the claim for the previous year(s).

Answer (score 330, accepted):

The copyright notice on a work establishes a claim to copyright. The date on the notice establishes how far back the claim is made. This means if you update the date, you are no longer claiming the copyright for the original date and that means if somebody has copied the work in the meantime and they claim its theirs on the ground that their publishing the copy was before your claim, then it will be difficult to establish who is the originator of the work.

Therefore, if the claim is based on common law copyright (not formally registered), then the date should be the date of first publication. If the claim is a registered copyright, then the date should be the date claimed in the registration. In cases where the work was substantially revised you may establish a new copyright claim to the revised work by adding another copyright notice with a newer date or by adding an additional date to the existing notice as in "© 2000, 2010". Again, the added date establishes how far back the claim is made on the revision.

Comment: Note, registration is a United States only mechanism. For (almost) everyone else the Berne Convention makes copyright automatic (you don't need a copyright statement... but the claim may make establishing that claim easier).

Comment: After some deliberation [on a reddit thread](http://redd.it/1p9tao), I've decided to drop the copyright date notices on my websites. -- (C) Chase Moskal -- is the way it looks now. I believe that nowadays, particularly for websites, the copyright publishing date is completely irrelevant. It serves no purpose at all, in or out of a courtroom. I update a "last updated" critter that is totally unrelated.

Comment: @Richard Just so that every future reader is clear: the USA copyright is just as automatic as that of basically every other country. It's automatically given, and you don't need a copyright statement. Registration and copyright statements only has the same effect as in any other country - it can in some cases make proving you own the copyright and fighting infringement easier. This has been the case for approximately two decades as of this writing.

Answer (score 60):

There is no reason at all for an individual to update the copyright year, because in the U.S. and Europe the life of copyright is the life of the author plus 70 years (50 years in some other countries like Canada and Australia).  Extending the date does not extend the copyright.  This also applies when a page has multiple contributors none of which are corporations.

As for corporations, Google doesn't update their copyright dates because they don't *care* whether some page they started in 1999 and updated this year falls into the public domain in 2094 or 2109.  And if they don't, why should you?  (As a Googler, now an ex-Googler, I was told this was the policy for internal source code as well.)

Comment: This is what the policy in my company seems to be also. Except that current copyright date in files gives further assurance to people that the code is alive and actively maintained, so there may be some value in updating the dates.

Comment: Copyright dates are an indirect, vague, and potentially misleading way to give this assurance. Much better to have a clear channel for bug reports or problems, respond in a timely manner to them, and make those conversations public except in the rare case where necessary.

Comment: @JonathanHartley Whilst you are correct about having dedicated channels for communication being the way to go - the fact is, the copyright dates on most websites and software products are extremely visible/apparent and typically occupy prime real estate, e.g. on splash and intro screens - therefore I think keeping them up-to-date is just-as important (for the case of offering reassurance)

Comment: @LintfordPickle But, also, amazon.com DO have one, and they have updated it to 2020, too. So clearly I'm at least half wrong. :-)

Comment: I also see Copyright {{ CurrentYear }} on lots of Google properties. 

In general, I think it is just an "optics" thing (keeping everything up to date). I've seen some places list the full date range e.g Copyright 1992-2021.

Comment: Might want to mention that for corporations a copyright lasts at least 95 years ([source](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-duration.html)).

Answer (score 20):

Your OCD is to blame :)

You do not have to put anything about copyright on your page - copyright automatically applies until you explicitly license it otherwise. Copyright also applies for a preset number of years as determined by international treaties. I do not know what the exact number of years is, but it is a lot, so there is absolutely no point in updating the year in your copyright notice.

Comment: It is true that all works are automatically copyrighted, however that only gets you the legal right to stop infringement.  You have to include a copyright notice to get compensatory and punitive damaged (at least in the U.S.).

Comment: @Daniel:  The copyright notice will help, but for full protection in the US you need to register your copyright.

Answer (score 19):

Technically, you should update a copyright year only if you made contributions to the work during that year. So if your website hasn't been updated in a given year, there is no ground to touch the file just to update the year.

Answer (score 13):

It is important to recognize that the copyright laws have changed and that for non-US sources, especially after the USA joining the Berne Convention on March 1, 1989, copyright registration in not necessary for enforcement of a copyright notice.

Here is a resumé quoted from the Cornell University Law School (copied on March 4, 2015 from https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/copyright:
"Copyright
copyright: an overview

> The U.S. Copyright Act, 17 U.S.C. §§ 101 - 810, is Federal legislation
> enacted by Congress under its Constitutional grant of authority to
> protect the writings of authors. See U.S. Constitution, Article I,
> Section 8. Changing technology has led to an ever expanding
> understanding of the word "writings." The Copyright Act now reaches
> architectural design, software, the graphic arts, motion pictures, and
> sound recordings. See § 106. As of January 1, 1978, all works of
> authorship fixed in a tangible medium of expression and within the
> subject matter of copyright were deemed to fall within the exclusive
> jurisdiction of the Copyright Act regardless of whether the work was
> created before or after that date and whether published or
> unpublished. See § 301. See also preemption.
>
> The owner of a copyright has the exclusive right to reproduce,
> distribute, perform, display, license, and to prepare derivative works
> based on the copyrighted work. See § 106. The exclusive rights of the
> copyright owner are subject to limitation by the doctrine of "fair
> use." See § 107. Fair use of a copyrighted work for purposes such as
> criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching, scholarship, or research
> is not copyright infringement.  To determine whether or not a
> particular use qualifies as fair use, courts apply a multi-factor
> balancing test. See § 107.
>
> Copyright protection subsists in original works of authorship fixed in
> any tangible medium of expression from which they can be perceived,
> reproduced, or otherwise communicated, either directly or with the aid
> of a machine or device. See § 102. Copyright protection does not
> extend to any idea, procedure, process, system, method of operation,
> concept, principle, or discovery. For example, if a book is written
> describing a new system of bookkeeping, copyright protection only
> extends to the author's description of the bookkeeping system; it does
> not protect the system itself. See Baker v. Selden, 101 U.S. 99
> (1879).
>
> According to the Copyright Act of 1976, registration of copyright is
> voluntary and may take place at any time during the term of
> protection. See § 408.  Although registration of a work with the
> Copyright Office is not a precondition for protection, an action for
> copyright infringement may not be commenced until the copyright has
> been formally registered with the Copyright Office. See § 411.
>
> Deposit of copies with the Copyright Office for use by the Library of
> Congress is a separate requirement from registration. Failure to
> comply with the deposit requirement within three months of publication
> of the protected work may result in a civil fine. See § 407. The
> Register of Copyrights may exempt certain categories of material from
> the deposit requirement.
>
> In 1989 the U.S. joined the Berne Convention for the Protection of
> Literary and Artistic Works. In accordance with the requirements of
> the Berne Convention, notice is no longer a condition of protection
> for works published after March 1, 1989. This change to the notice
> requirement applies only prospectively to copies of works publicly
> distributed after March 1, 1989.
>
> The Berne Convention also modified the rule making copyright
> registration a precondition to commencing a lawsuit for infringement.
> For works originating from a Berne Convention country, an infringement
> action may be initiated without registering the work with the U.S.
> Copyright Office.  However, for works of U.S. origin, registration
> prior to filing suit is still required.
>
> The federal agency charged with administering the act is the Copyright
> Office of the Library of Congress. See § 701 of the act. Its
> regulations are found in Parts 201 - 204 of title 37 of the Code of
> Federal Regulations."

Answer (score 3):

Copyright should be up to the date of publish.

So, if it's a static content (such as the Times article you linked to), it should probably be statically copyrighted.

If it's dynamically generated content, it should be copyrighted to the current year

Comment: Your suggestion to automatically update the copyright looks suspect to me.  Legally, only humans are creative, and use machines to create things.  If you haven't updated the software yourself, I don't know if updating the notice is correct.  Consult a lawyer specializing in copyright law if you need to know.

Comment: @David - this is how all the enterprise web sites I ever dealt with worked, so I assume it was vetted by company's lawyers at one point or another. Good advice re: lawyer, though

Comment: Downvoted because I believe it is factually incorrect. You don't need to add a copyright notice at all - you automatically own the copyright to all created works. Should you have to go to court over it, your git history will provide greater proof of creation dates than a copyright date you type yourself. Whether dynamically generated or not, if you do not add new content, then you have no basis to make a new copyright claim, so adding a new copyright date is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they are reprinting paper books each year. The copyright of the year when the book was printed is valid in all next years.

The same principle should apply to web pages, too. However "the year when website was created" is a bit different. So, if you make changes to your web site - you are not done yet. Hence, when updating the site, you may want to update the copyright year.

Comment: A reprint of the same work would never establish a new date of the work itself. If the work is revised (new edition) then a new date would be established.